# How to drop observations after a certain condition has been met in Python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a pandas dataframe and I want to delete observations with the same name after they met the condition (cond=1).

My dataset looks like:

```
person    cond
  A         0    
  A         0    
  A         1
  A         0
  A         0
  B         0 
  B         1
  C         1
  C         0
```

I want to get this:

```
person    cond
  A         0    
  A         0
  A         1    
  B         0 
  B         1    
  C         1
```

I want the code to first check if the next person has the same name, then check if the condition is met (cond=1) and if so drop all the next lines with the same name.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `groupby` and `apply` a `lambda` that slices the df from the start until the first max value using `idxmax`, which in this case will be the first `1` value:

```
In [16]:
df.groupby('person')['cond'].apply( lambda x: x.loc[:x.idxmax()]).reset_index()

Out[16]:
  person  level_1  cond
0      A        0     0
1      A        1     0
2      A        2     1
3      B        5     0
4      B        6     1
5      C        7     1
```

You can also make an additional call to `drop` to remove the `'level_1'` col:

```
In [23]:
df.groupby('person')['cond'].apply( lambda x: x.loc[:x.idxmax()]).reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1)

Out[23]:
  person  cond
0      A     0
1      A     0
2      A     1
3      B     0
4      B     1
5      C     1
```

**update**

to handle the situation where you have no `1` in the group we can test if this is the case in the `lambda`:

```
In [24]:
import pandas as pd
import io
# setup some data
t="""person    cond
  A         0    
  A         0    
  A         1
  A         0
  A         0
  B         0 
  B         1
  C         1
  C         0
  D         0
  D         0"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), delim_whitespace=True)
df

Out[24]:
   person  cond
0       A     0
1       A     0
2       A     1
3       A     0
4       A     0
5       B     0
6       B     1
7       C     1
8       C     0
9       D     0
10      D     0

In [29]:
df.groupby('person')['cond'].apply( lambda x: x.loc[:x.idxmax()] if len(x[x==0]) != len(x) else x)

Out[29]:
person    
A       0     0
        1     0
        2     1
B       5     0
        6     1
C       7     1
D       9     0
        10    0
Name: cond, dtype: int64
```

So here we test if all values are `0` and if so just return the group otherwise we slice as before

Comment: I was about to write how to use .dublicate with multiple cols, but this is much better answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried to use this but now he is also dropping all the observations which only have cond=0. I forgot to mention this option. It can also be the case that a person only has zeros. In that case I don't want to drop any of the observations.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly! Is it also an option to add more columns? I tried to extend this code but it's not working with more than two columns.